# PG (node-postgres) VS. sequelize

Tags: node.js, pg, sequelize.js

I just want to ask which database module is better, PG or sequelize? I heard that sequelize has sometimes problem with transaction. Thanks

Comment: Sequelize isn't a database module, it's an ORM, which relies on PG to work.

Answer (score 37):

PG is a raw driver - it simply allows us to send queries to database, and sequelize is an ORM (object relation mapper - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Object-relational_mapping) - the high level module, that maps objects to database entries.

The usage of any of them depends on the scale of the project.
If project is a 100 line of codes utility - I prefer raw driver.
If project is quite big and have to be scalable and maintainable - I think `sequelize` is better.

Also using `sequelize` with very few changes in code you can change the database you use - from postgresql to mysql/sqlite.

It is worth noting, that you can use both modules in the same project - in part depending on transaction you can use `pg`, and `sequelize` for other parts

Answer (score 0):

`Sequelize` supports two kinds of transaction, managed and unmanaged transaction. In unmanaged transactions, user manually defines committing and rolling back by calling `sequelize` methods. In managed transactions, `sequelize` automatically rollback the transaction in case of an error.

As for `node-postgres` and `sequelize` are concerns. Here are some of pros and cons.

`node-progress`:

- Pros:

  - It's simple and lightweight library that sends queries directly to the database.
- Cons:

  - It doesn't provide high-level abstractions like an ORM does.

`Sequelize`:

- Pros:

  - It provides high level abstractions which make it easier to work with the databases.
  - It allows to change a database you use with a very few changes in the code.
- Cons:

  - It has steeper learning curve than using a simple raw driver like `node-postgress`.

Hope this helps.